# Nginx - Building from source - not working

Tags: linux, nginx

I was using this code to install Nginx

```
aptitude -y install nginx
aptitude -y full-upgrade
```

This was working fine. However, I want to install my apps from source to give me more control. I then used this code:

```
cd /opt/
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz nginx-1.2.3.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.2.3
./configure
make
make install
```

However, it seems to have extracted and installed fine on the server, but I cant see anything on my site. The command used to restart my Nginx also no longer works:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Is anyone able to give me a bit more information on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check, where the server was installed. Probably it was installed to the `/usr/local/bin` directory. And the binary, that it specified in `/etc/init.d/nginx` is in `/usr/bin`.

Also, you can add `set -x` as the second line in the `/etc/init.d/nginx` to see what happens when you start it.